# AJAX reload page before get content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fullpage.js

I am using FullPage.js plugin, i am trying to make navigation between pages with AJAX.

When i am using .load(); i am catching page i need, but, as i see now i need to reload fullpage.js, because loaded page isnt active, script doesnt work with it.

Here is my code:

```
$('.click a').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $.ajax(this.href, {

                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#fullpage').html($(data).find('#fullpage > *'));

                    location.search = "reloaded=1";
                    console.log('The page has been successfully loaded');
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('An error occurred');
                }
            });
        });
```

How can i refresh plugin, or can i load page before i get its content with AJAX?

Maybe i can load page with AJAX already been loaded?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating sections or slides on the fly, then you would need to destroy and initialize fullPage.js again. 
To do so, you would need to use the [`destroy('all')`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#destroytype) function of fullPage.js and then initialize it again.

Something like:

```
//initializing fullpage.js for the 1st time.
initFullpage();

function myFunction() {
    $('.click a').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(this.href, {

            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#fullpage').html($(data).find('#fullpage > *'));

                location.search = "reloaded=1";
                console.log('The page has been successfully loaded');

                //destroying fullpage.js completely
                $.fn.fullpage.destroy('all');

                //initializing it again so it can detect new sections.
                initFullpage();
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('An error occurred');
            }
        });
    });
}

function initFullpage(){
     $('#fullpage').fullpage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try use a function :

```
function myFunction(){
  $('.click a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(this.href, {

            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#fullpage').html($(data).find('#fullpage > *'));

                location.search = "reloaded=1";
                console.log('The page has been successfully loaded');
                myFunction(); // FOR refresh 
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('An error occurred');
            }
        });
    });
}
```